# eliminating redundant tuples

Tags: python, tuples

If I have a list of tuples, where each tuple represents variables, `a`, `b` and `c`, how can I eliminate redundant tuples?

Redundant tuples are those where `a` and `b` are simply interchanged, but `c` is the same. So for this example:

```
tups = [(30, 40, 50), (40, 30, 50), (20, 48, 52), (48, 20, 52)]
```

my final list should only contain only half of the entries. One possible output:

```
tups = [(30, 40, 50), (20, 48, 52)]
```

another

```
tups = [(40, 30, 50), (20, 48, 52)]
```

etc.

Is there an easy Pythonic way to do this?

I tried using sets, but `(30, 40, 50)` is different from `(40, 30, 50)`, but to me these are redundant and I'd just like to keep one of them (doesn't matter which, but if I could pick I'd prefer the low to high value order). If there was a way to sort the first 2 elements of the tuples, then using the set would work.

I am sure I could hack together a working solution (perhaps converting tuples to lists as intermediate step), but I just wanted to see if there's an easy and obvious way to do this that I'm not familiar with.

PS: This question partially motivated by [PE #39](http://projecteuler.net/problem=39). But even aside from this PE problem, I am now just curious how this could be done easily (or if).

**Edit**:

Just to provide a bit of context for those not familiar with PE #39 - `a`, `b`, and `c` represent sides of a right triangle, so I'm checking if `a**2 + b**2 == c**2`, clearly the order of `a` and `b` don't matter.

Comment: Actually, `set((30, 40, 50)) == set((40, 30, 50))`.

Comment: @Lenna: But, `set([(30, 40, 50), (40, 30, 50)]) != set([(30, 40, 50)])`.

Comment: @JoelCornett: I was referring to the OP's statement, "I tried using sets, but `(30, 40, 50)` is different from `(40, 30, 50)`"

Comment: @Lenna: And that statement was correct.  Your example is a set not of the tuples `(30, 40, 50)` and `(40, 30, 50)` but of the numbers 30, 40, and 50.

Comment: @Lenna Perhaps I phrased it poorly, I was trying to use the `set` to eliminate duplicates (as I define them as redundant) in my list of tuples (as one would ordinarily do when trying to eliminate duplicates in a list of simple values)

Comment: @BrenBarn: Look at the parentheses. `set((30, 40, 50))` _is_ a set of the tuple `(30, 40, 50)`. `set(30, 40, 50)` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Lenna: Look at the result.  `len(set((30, 40, 50)))` is 3.  It is a set of three elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
set([(a,b,c) if a<b else (b,a,c) for a,b,c in tups])
```

Comment: Or if your Python supports it, `{(a,b,c) if a<b else (b,a,c) for a,b,c in tups}`.

Comment: @minitech Could you elaborate on your comment? Also what version of Python?

Comment: Derivative variant: `{(min(a,b), max(a,b), c) for a,b,c in tups}`, or in Python 3: `{(min(ab), max(ab), c) for *ab, c in tups}`

Comment: @Levon: It's "new" in Python 2.7.

Comment: @minitech Just to clarify, this is "set comprehension" in place of list comprehension right?  Other than saving the final step of converting the list to set (which is good a good enough reason) are there are other benefits to this? (I'm happy to upvote this if you post it as an answer too)

Comment: That turns `[(20, 10, 30)]` into `[(10, 20, 30)]` - is that right?

Comment: @Levon: Oh, no, it's just a more concise syntax for the same thing.

Comment: @minitech So *not* set comprehension vs list comprehension that is convert to set at the end?

Answer (score 4):

```
tups = [(30, 40, 50), (40, 30, 50), (20, 48, 52), (48, 20, 52)] 
no_duplicates = list(set(tuple(sorted(tup)) for tup in tups))
```

Of course this is assuming that the 3rd element of each tuple will always be the largest element in each tuple, otherwise, do this:

```
no_duplicates = list(set(tuple(sorted(tup[:2])) + (tup[2],) for tup in tups))
```

As WolframH suggested, the expression `tuple(sorted(tup[:2])) + (tup[2],)` can be written as `tuple(sorted(tup[:2])) + tup[2:]`, which is advantageous because it can be generalized to `tuple(sorted(tup[:i])) + tup[i:]`, where `i` can be any point that one wants to separate the sorted elements from the unsorted elements.

Comment: Can't hash a list either.  You'd need to convert back to tuples, I think.

Comment: You can write `(tup[2],)` as `tup[2:]`.

Comment: @WolframH: I like that. especially because it can be extended to `sorted(tup[:i]) + tup[i:]` :)

Answer (score 4):

From your question, it seems that the first two elements of your tuples form a sub-unit within the tuple.  Therefore it would seem to make sense to restructure your data as a tuple of a tuple and a third number, where the first tuple is the first two numbers in sorted order.  Then you can naturally use sets:

```
>>> newTups = [(tuple(sorted([a, b])), c) for a, b, c in tups]
>>> newTups
[((30, 40), 50), ((30, 40), 50), ((20, 48), 52), ((20, 48), 52)]
>>> set(newTups)
set([((20, 48), 52), ((30, 40), 50)])
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to "unpack" these?

Comment: @Levon: You can unpack the elements of such a tuple with, e.g. `(a, b), c = newTups[0]`.

Comment: +1 thanks for this solution (re unpacking, I was looking for this: `[(i[0][0], i[0][1],i[1]) for i in set(newTups)]` and got it to work fine)

Answer (score 2):

Convert each of your tuples into a `frozenset` and create a `set` of these frozensets.

```
tups = [(30, 40, 50), (40, 30, 50), (20, 48, 52), (48, 20, 52)]

frozen_sets = { frozenset(x) for x in tups }

tups2 = [tuple(x) for x in frozen_sets]
```

This works because `frozenset([1,2,3]) == frozenset([3,1,2])`, in contrast to tuples, where `(1,2,3) != (3,1,2)`.

You have to convert the tuples into `frozenset`s rather than simple `set`s because you get the following error when you try to make one set a member of another set:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

`frozenset`s are hashable, and so avoid this problem.

Comment: +1 cool -- thank you, haven't worked with frozensets before. (by the way, You forgot the `in` in your list comprehension)

Comment: +1. I just wrote an answer with `[tuple(fs) for fs in {frozenset(t) for t in tups}]` then saw it was a dup of yours an hour earlier! Deleted mine...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about the order for the first two elements, you don't really want to use 3-uples : just convert to a new data structure which discards the information you do not need.

```
result = {({x[0],x[1]},x[2]) for x in tups}
```

Comment: That won't quite work; you can't hash a set, so you'd have to use a `frozenset`.

Comment: @DSM : oops... Too long since I last wrote any Python ! The other two answer are satisfactory, just disregard mine.